# Return value of WaitForObject

Tags: multithreading, winapi, synchronization

What is the return value of the `WaitForObject()` function?

I do not mean the type of return value (int).

What does it return if the event is signalled and what does it return if the event is not signalled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `WaitForObject` function. I assume that you mean either `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

`WaitForSingleObject` will return `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, `WAIT_OBJECT_0` or `WAIT_ERROR`. `WaitForMultipleObjects` will return `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + n` (where n is the index to the object in the array) or `WAIT_ERROR`.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't C++. C++ has no API called `WaitForObject`.
The Windows API has a function called `WaitForSingleObject` and another called `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

These functions return -1 on failure, 0 if the first object in the array is signalled, and   a number >= 0x80 if the wait times out or is abandoned. (0x80 if abandoned, 0x102 if there is a timeout).